# same calibration images,but camera calibration result are different by Matlab cameraCalibrator、GML、OpenCV

Tags: camera, camera-calibration, calibration

i met a problem w.r.t camera calibration,i used three method(or tools),which are Opencv,GML,Matlab,but finally i get the extremely different result,and i was very confused about that,please help me out.

and i found GML(http://graphics.cs.msu.ru/en/node/909) has three method,which are native Opencv,modified opencv,new method,which can get extremely different results

Comment: Explain us a little more what are the different outcomes you found (intrinsic and extrinsic parameter?)

Comment: hey,i have solved this problem,the reason was that i place the chessboard far away from the camera(nearly 5m ), and the chessboard was printed on A3 paper,so the result was unstable